# Free Nagios virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machines, nagios

Where can a I get a quality, free VM of Nagios?

http://www.nagios-on-cd.org/ seems to be dead, and the [VMware appliance directory](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/cat/0?k=nagios) only lists JumpBox (good quality, but paid) and several other very old VMs of Nagios with no download link.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to spend a couple of minutes to install Nagios yourself? Either way you'll need to do the same amount of configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Icinga](http://www.icinga.org/) is a fork of Nagios (we're using at my office and are quite happy with it).  They provide a virtual appliance at http://www.icinga.org/about/virtual-appliance/.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you build nagios yourself, otherwise when it comes to configuration, which is about.... 99% of the work, that is where you'll have a problem.

Install Nagios in a CentOS vm, there are various guides on the internet the CentOS mailing list, and the Nagios mailing list are very helpful. In fact, you should be able to get a basic setup up and running in 24 hours, easily.

I would also suggest IRC - in fact, if you really need a hand, I've just done a nagios build, and I can advise you if you like :)

Comment: This^. Everytime I've used an appliance, it came back to bite me when something went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try [opsview community edition VM](http://www.opsview.com/downloads/opsview-3-vmware-virtual-appliance), it is based on nagios. I have 2 VMs working, one for internal services, other for hosting services.